# Positive lookahead regex to tokenize text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to tokenize the following text:

`F.B.I. is an acronym. FBI is an acronym, c.i.a. could also be one. $1,000,000.00 is a currency value as well as 1.000.000,00£ for example. Here is a measure cm24.54 and 34.3cm...`

like this:

`F.B.I. | is | an | acronym | . | FBI | is | an | acronym | , | c.i.a. | could | also | be | one | . | $ | 1,000,000.00 | is | a | currency | value | as | well | as | 1.000.000,00 | £ | for | example | . | Here | is | a | measure | cm | 24,54 | and | 34.3 | cm | ...`

I have started writing a regex to do this but I'm not sure how to keep acronyms and numbers together.

My regex looks like this: `str.split(/\s|(?=[^A-Za-z0-9#@])/)`, it splits and throws away whitespaces and it splits on non alphanumeric characters (excluding `#` and `@`) without removing them by using a positive lookahead.

How do I modify my regex to split the text as described above?

Comment: Why the downvotes + close request? How is it too broad?

Comment: You should lay out a clear logic to what you consider a token. For example, why is the `.` at the end of `F.B.I.` not token, but the `.` at the end of `example.` is?

Comment: @blhsing that is because it is an acronym ie. `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}`

Comment: I dont get how `\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}` matches my acronyms but `(?=(\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,}))` does not split them correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to pick out tokens than to pick out holes. Just go down the list, fix weird stuff, move subexpressions around till they do what you want. Remember that in `A|B`, `A` has priority. For example, this seems to work for the snippet above:

```js
let re = /\$|\£|cm|\.{3,}|[0-9,.]+|(?:\w\.){2,}|[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|[-\w]+/g;
let text = "F.B.I. is an acronym. FBI is an acronym, c.i.a. could also be one. $1,000,000.00 is a currency value as well as 1.000.000,00£ for example. Here is an email address email@address.com and a measure cm24.54 and 34.3cm...";
console.log(text.match(re));
```

However, note that this is very much an exercise of cataloguing exceptions. There will certainly be things that you'll miss, or that will end up wrong, or even cases where you need contradictory rules based on context.

EDIT: This was what I was talking in comments, but if you have it figured out great.

```js
let re = /(\$|\£|cm|\.{3,}|[0-9,.]+|(?:\w\.){2,}|[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|[-\w]+)/g;
let text = "F.B.I. is an acronym. FBI is an acronym, c.i.a. could also be one. $1,000,000.00 is a currency value as well as 1.000.000,00£ for example. Here is an email address email@address.com and a measure cm24.54 and 34.3cm...";
let theSplit = text.split(re);
console.log("The split:", JSON.stringify(theSplit));
let stuffBetween = theSplit.filter((e, i) => i % 2 == 0);
console.log("Just the stuff between:", JSON.stringify(stuffBetween));
```

Comment: Any reason to that preference? Because it's either much harder, or impossible (I'm still trying to decide). `split` can't consume the string, so it can match repeatedly at inconvenient spots with no tools to stop it from doing so (in particular since you lack the left context, given that JS doesn't implement lookbehind).

Comment: No idea exactly what you need, but you can use split in reverse by enclosing the entire body of regexp in parentheses. On a train now, will code up an example later if i remember :p

Comment: actually... match can work... thank you. this is what i'm going to use: `/[A-Za-z]+(?=[0-9])|[0-9,.]+|(?:\w\.){2,}|[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+|[-\w]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this just using a regex, as an example take `.`. It could be the end of a sentence, a decimal point, the thousands separator as used in several European languages or part of an ASCIIfied ellipsis `...` instead of `…`. The [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) project has some rules for breaking text into sentences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this can be done using regex, just not sure how...